# Xpath how find element containing text containing unicode?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, unicode

I am e.g. trying to find something like this on an international websites:

unicode: `"\u202aDansk\u202c\u200f"`
html: `&#x202A;Dansk&#x202C;&rlm;`

This doesn't work: `//*[contains(text(),'&#x202A;Dansk&#x202C;&rlm;')]`

Comment: Add a relevant xml sample . Questions must provide a [mcve]

Comment: It turned out, that this problem only occurs in the browser developer menu but not using selenium

Comment: @Fauna what are you doing in the browser development menu (do you mean console?) - you should be evaluating: `$x("//*[contains(text(),'&#x202A;Dansk&#x202C;&rlm;')]")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPath itself does not provide any way of escaping non-ASCII characters. But the host language in which XPath strings are written often does.

When XPath expressions are written as string literals in a programming language such as Java, C#, Python, or Javascript, you can generally use backslash escaping:

```
xpath.evaluate("contains(., '\u202aDansk\u202c\u200f')")
```

When XPath expressions are written as attributes in an XML-based language such as XSLT or XSD, you can use ampersand escaping:

```
select="contains(., '&#x202a;Dansk&#x202c;&#x200f;')"
```

In any other context, you'll need to check the specs for your host language environment.

Comment: you could add python to the list of languages supporting backslash unicode escape